# What's wrong with this syntax for passing an App Engine TaskQueue to a Backend?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, backend, task-queue

I tried the following to pass a TaskQueue to a [Backend](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/backends.html) but it didn't work.

Is there a problem with this syntax?

```
try{
    Queue queue = QueueFactory.getQueue("pine");
    TaskOptions options = TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl("/pine/task/getbusy");

    options = options.param("taskparams", params);
    options = options.header("Host",
    BackendServiceFactory.getBackendService().getBackendAddress("pinetask", 1));

    queue.add(options);
}
```

backend.xml:

```
<backends>
  <backend name="pinetask">
    <class>B2</class>
    <instances>1</instances>
    <max-concurrent-requests>1</max-concurrent-requests>
    <options>
      <public>false</public>
      <dynamic>true</dynamic>
    </options>
  </backend>
</backends>
```

Comment: I presume by "pass a task queue to a backend", you mean "run a task on a backend"? What happens when you try?

Answer (score 2):

Because Instances 1 mean index 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

try this for the "Host" header:

options = options.header("Host",
    BackendServiceFactory.getBackendService().getBackendAddress("pinetask"));